# Cyclic quadrilateral properties

Tags: geometry

A cyclic quadrilateral has lengths $(L_1 ,L_2, L_3 , L_4) $ in cyclic order.

What is the radius of the circle?
What are the four internal angles?
What are the two external angles made by producing opposite sides?

A 4-bar mechanism has maximum area as a cyclic quadrilateral in the above configuration by Brahmagupta's result. Is this correct? If so, any proof, of may be an already asked question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Formulas for radius and internal angles are given in [Wikipedia's "Cyclic Quadrilateral" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral). The external angles may take a little work. I'm not sure about the $4$-bar mechanism.

Comment: @Blue If external angles are worked out, they may be included in Wiki. They too would have  the beauty of symmetry.

Comment: Actually, the external angles are there, too, under ["Angle Formulas"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral#Angle_formulas). (I didn't scroll down past the angle-between-diagonals formula before.)